# How do I qualify as a sub-editor?

Tags: editing

I've seen a lot of sub-editing jobs advertised lately and I'm wondering what qualifications (and experience?) such a role would require. Is there a particular sub-editing/proofreading course I should do? And do I need to complete an inDesign course? I've seen a few job descriptions stating the sub-editor will deal with putting the text into layout too.
Thanks.

Comment: Learning InDesign is never going to *hurt* your chances of being an editor, particularly if it's not in the job description and you volunteer that you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd need a degree or equivalent certification in journalism or communication. Experience in writing, proof reading, doing layout, editing however minor,working with headlines, familiarity with modern styles and current events would also be a plus. Subeditor position do involve doing layout so having an inDesign course would help. There are few specific courses that get you the qualification needed to become sub editor.